# Graphics connections vs USB

Tags: storage

Why aren't graphics connections such as HDMI used for peripheral devices such as storage drives - in addition to graphics?

It seems these connections are capable of moving data very fast compared to current USB standards, so I'm wondering why back up storage devices (as one example) can't be connected to, say, a spare HDMI or DisplayPort connection for faster I/O?

Is this a theoretical possibility, but limited by driver development, or does the graphics hardware just not handle the data/file-types associated with storage?

Comment: Dell has user HDMI as stack connectors in some of their networking switches. However, this site is about practical, not theoretical (or "why"/"why don't") questions. We cannot give an empirical reason why HDMI has not been used for these.

Comment: What is your use case?  The primary devices that have HDMI or Displayports are TVs and blu-ray(optical) disc, and none of them have CPU that can't handle those kinds of speeds even if they were possible.  Most TV and many other devices come with USB ports that are fast enough for their use case.  The newest USB support 80g/80g or 120g/40g what do you need that is faster?  Faster devices use PCIe.  HDMI ports inclusion add costly licensing fees especially to the manufacturer.  Even if they did it today, it would be 10 years before adoptions was wide enough to be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Graphics card display outputs are almost entirely expected to push data in one direction, out to the monitor.

The electronics is, as a result, entirely configured only for that purpose. In order to take data in it would need extra electronics, and probably more wires in the connectors to allow data to come back.

If all you were wanting is a Write Once, Read Never (WORN) kind of storage device then HDMI would probably be quite good at it. In order to get data back it is currently less than optimal.

USB 3 on the other hand is a very high speed data connection which uses multiple sets of wires to transfer data in both directions.  In order to transmit video it actually switches over some of the data lines in the cable using a multiplexer device. You lose some of the USB data lines and gain display data.

One such device is the TUSB1046 from Texas Instruments:

[image]

In order for Displayport or HDMI to transfer data they would need some kind of data switch that allowed some of the data lines in the cable to become bi-directional and to bypass the graphics card display output.

In the end it boils down to there being no need to run data over a HDMI cable or connector because we already have better dedicated connectors that are already better positioned, both electronically and physically, to transfer data.

Comment: In addition to the issues with HDMI mentioned, it also implements High-bandwidth Digital Content Protection (HDCP), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection, which likely would interfere with transmission of digital **data**.

Comment: "_If all you were wanting is a Write Once, Read Never (WORN) kind of storage device then HDMI would probably be quite good at it_" ... to be fair though, a display is exactly that - send a frame and poof, it's gone, never to be seen again!

Comment: @Attie In fairness a display is more Write Once Read Once while you are looking at it and Write Once Read Never when you look away or blink. Of course display capture cards can change that dynamic into a more circular system of Write Twice Read Once Copy The Other, but WTROCTO doesn't have anywhere like the same kind of ring to it.

Answer (score 2):

Thunderbolt is, roughly, what you are proposing.

Originally Thunderbolt (1/2) was routed over the Mini Displayport connector.  Instead of carrying Displayport video, you could switch the port into Thunderbolt mode which could carry Displayport video plus PCI Express.  The latter was useful for various I/O, including USB, networking and storage (SATA or NVMe).  Displayport can easily be converted to HDMI if that is the kind of monitor you have.

When Thunderbolt 3 came along, they switched to using the USB-C connector.  Now the connector can carry various combinations of Displayport, PCIe, and USB.  It got more flexible with Thunderbolt 4.

Thunderbolt is able to negotiate bandwidth sharing between the various protocols, so if you need more bandwidth for a second monitor then it takes some away from the data connection, out of the total 40Gbps, but in the outward direction only, not in the inward direction.